# wrapping preg_replace repeated groups individually

Tags: php, regex

I've got a simple regular expression in PHP which I am using to replace in a string.

```
$pat='/\$(\w+)/';
$repl='f("${1}")';
echo preg_replace($pat,$repl,'This is a $test.');
```

So for example, this translates:

```
This is a $test.
```

into:

```
This is a f("test")
```

But now I want to change this slightly so that I can match multiple comma separated words and individually wrap them, like so:

```
This is a $test,red,green,blue.
```

should become:

```
This is a f("test","red","green","blue")
```

I can come up with the pattern easily:

```
$pat='/\$([\w,]+)/';
```

But I am at a loss as to how to individually wrap the each element of the repeated group.  Using the existing replacement I get:

```
This is a f("test,red,green,blue")
```

Trying something like:

```
$repl='f(${"1"})';
```

wrecks the reference and obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you have to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and then just slightly modify your replacement with a callback function, where you first [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your comma separated match into an array and then [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it back to a string where you can put your quotes around it, e.g.

Replacement:

```
$repl = function($m){
    return 'f("' . implode("\",\"", explode(",", $m[1])) . '")';
};
```

Function call:

```
preg_replace($pat, $repl, $str); → preg_replace_callback($pat, $repl, $str);
```

Comment: i think there is a missing or extra quote somewhere in that function?

Comment: @Michael Yes, something really messed up, when I copied that out of my editor. Now the replacement should be correct.